# Cursor hotkeys for Mac

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

On Windows, I'm pretty quick with the cursor hotkeys. Like:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> / <kbd>End</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> / <kbd>End</kbd>

to move around the input area without using a mouse.

Does something like this exist for Mac OSX? If not, anyone know of an app that can add that functionality in?

I think this is one of my biggest issues with the differences between the two platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

⌘← / ⌘→: move to beginning or end of line
⌘↑ / ⌘↓: move to beginning or end of view
⌥← / ⌥→: move word left or right
⌥↑ / ⌥↓, ⌃A / ⌃E: move to beginning or end of paragraph
↖ / ↘: scroll to beginning or end of view
⌥⇞ / ⌥⇟: page up or down and move the caret
⌘⌫: delete to beginning of line
⌃K: delete to end of paragraph
⌥⌫ / ⌥⌦: delete word backward or forward
⌥↩ / ⌥⇥: insert newline or tab ignoring field editor

Adding shift to the navigation shortcuts modifies selections. Symbols used for keys:

⌘: command, ⇧: shift, ⌥: option, ⌃: control
↖: home, ↘: end, ⇞: page up, ⇟: page down
⌫: delete (backspace on other platforms), ⌦: forward delete (delete on other platforms)
↩: return (enter on other platforms), ⇥: tab

Most of the default text editing shortcuts are defined in [StandardKeyBinding.dict](http://lri.me/keybindings.html). You could replace them with Windows-style shortcuts [by creating a DefaultKeyBinding.dict or by using KeyRemap4MacBook](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68716/emacsify-osx-throughout-word-forward-f-and-word-backward-b-instead/71087#71087), but it's probably easier to just learn the default shortcuts.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> / <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>     Beginning/End of line

<kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> / <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>     Beginning/End of Word

<kbd>⌥+⌘</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> / <kbd>⌥+⌘</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>     Previous/Next tab in most Apps

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> To switch windows in a same app

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇥</kbd> Opens the quick switch between apps (like <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>⇥</kbd> on windows), when it is opened, you can move with the <kbd>arrow</kbd> keys to select an app, you can use the <kbd>H</kbd> key to hide the app, the <kbd>M</kbd> key to minimise, the <kbd>Q</kbd> to quit the app.

If you have a Mac keyboard <kbd>F3</kbd> will show Exposé, <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> will show the desktop.

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to start a Spotlight search (very important and useful to launch apps, do some simple maths etc.)

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>?</kbd> to launch the Help menu in every app.

Something you might miss from Windows (Cut and paste) :

Copy : <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

Paste : <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

Paste (cut) : <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd>  + <kbd>V</kbd>

Comment: Pretty helpful! I'll try it out and see how it goes. A bummer (but understandable) the Windows ones aren't the same.